# Visibility of python class attributes

Tags: python, quantlib

I am fairly new to Python, and trying to write a wrapper class around some Quantlib swap objects. Problem is that I am trying to call the Qualtlib Schedule object using attributes that have been either passed to the constructor or calculated in the constructor. Problem is when I run the code as such;

```
 import swapleg as sl

Leg1 = sl.SwapLeg("Fix","AUD",ql.Date(26, 9, 2018),ql.Date(26, 9, 2028),ql.Monthly)
print(Leg1.EffectiveDate)
Leg1.showSchedule()
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
September 26th, 2018
  .......
AttributeError: type object 'SwapLeg' has no attribute 'EffectiveDate'
```

The code is listed  - the object Leg1 gets instantiated, and the EffectiveDate does get set. My issue is that when the showSchedule call the Quantlib call ql.Schedule, it loses visibility to the EffectiveDate, even though I am looking it with self.EffectiveDate. Clearly I am missing something here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import QuantLib as ql

class SwapLeg:

    def __init__(self,LegType,CCY,EffectiveDate=None,TerminationDate=None,Tenor=None,Rate=None,Spread=None):
                self.LegType=LegType
                self.CCY=CCY
                self.Tenor=Tenor
                if EffectiveDate is None:
                    self.EffectiveDate = ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate
                else:
                    self.EffectiveDate =EffectiveDate
                ......

    def _LegSchedule(self):
        ls = ql.Schedule(   self.EffectiveDate,
                            self.TerminationDate,
                            self.Tenor,
                            self.Calendar,
                            self.businessDayConvention,
                            self.businessDayConvention,
                            self.GenRule,
                            self.EndOfMonth,
                            self.FirstDate,
                            self.NextToLastDate)
        return ls

    @classmethod
    def showSchedule(self):
        for i, d in enumerate(self._LegSchedule(self)):
            print("{0} {1}".format(i+1,d))
```

Comment: Why does `showSchedule` have `@classmethod` on it?

Comment: The placing `self.EffectiveDate` in if statements is kind of strange. Could you set it to `self.EffectiveDate = None` first before the if statements? Seems redundant I know but see if you can at least access the property with that first.

Comment: Take the `@classmethod` off. It's an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: A `classmethod` will receive the class as the first argument, not the instance. It would be better to name it `cls` instead of `self`.

Comment: Ahh yes - removing of @classmethod seems to have fixed the issue. Makes sense now.